# SQL Server : splitting string into different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I've done some searching and found some examples but it doesn't seem to work for my question.

I'm writing a report and one column in the Contact table has one or more email addresses in, for example -

```
Column_name_email
123@test.com, 456@test.com, 789@test.ca
```

I would like to split the above into three columns

```
Email1, Email2, Email3
```

If there is only one email then two columns will be blank and `Email1` populated.

Comment: Probably a bad idea to make separate *columns* you probably want them in *tows* instead. In other words, you need a separate table, `ContactEmail` that has na FK to the `Contact` table

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string_split()` and then conditional aggregation:

```
select t.*, s.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as email1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as email2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then value end) as email3
      from (select trim(s.value) as value,
                   row_number() over (order by charindex(',' + s.value + ',', ',' + t.email + ',')) as seqnum
            from string_split(t.email, ',') s
           ) s
    ) s;
```

Unfortunately, `string_split()` does not preserve ordering.  Aaron Bertrand has a good discussion on this [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282790/are-the-results-of-the-string-split-function-returned-in-a-deterministic-order).

Comment: Note that `STRING_SPLIT()` not only requires SQL Server 2016, but your database must have it's compatibility level set to 130 (SQL Server 2016) or higher. Note also that the sister "inverse" function, `STRING_AGG()`, wasn't introduced until SQL Server 2017.

Comment: String_split() does not guarantee order, nor does `order by (select null)` - if that matters.

Comment: @SMor . . . I "know" I saw a reference by Aaron Bertrand that it actually did preserve ordering but wasn't documented.  That said, I linked to a recent discussion that says the opposite.  Perhaps I misunderstand the reference (which I now cannot find).  So I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks all I'll give that ago.

Answer (score 2):

Just another option using a bit of JSON.  Unlike string_split() ... this will maintain the sequence if required

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Column_name_email] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('123@test.com, 456@test.com, 789@test.ca')
 
Select A.[Column_name_email]
      ,B.* 
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Email1 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]'))
                      ,Email2 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]'))
                      ,Email3 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[2]'))
                 From  ( values ( '["'+replace(replace([Column_name_email],'"','\"'),',','","')+'"]' ) ) B1(S)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Column_name_email                       Email1           Email2          Email3
123@test.com, 456@test.com, 789@test.ca 123@test.com     456@test.com    789@test.ca
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give this ago.